# Solaris 5.10 x86 CC linker error: ld: fatal: library -lcryptoki: not found

Tags: c++, linker, x86, solaris, ld

we have SPARC project to port to x86 with static linking.
The final step with CC compiler in the linker fails:

**ld: fatal: library -lcryptoki: not found
ld: fatal: library -lrt: not found
ld: fatal: library -lsocket: not found**
etc.

The path to the libs are:
/usr/local/lib
/opt/csw/lib

Where are these libs have gone?
Thanks!

Comment: With -dy option the ld complains that -locci and -lclntsh not found.

Comment: *With -dy option the ld complains that -locci and -lclntsh not found.* Those appear to be Oracle client libraries.  Link them per the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 10 removed system static libraries.  You must dynamically link Solaris 10 (and later) executables.

[**Features Removed from the Solaris 10 Operating System**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/html/817-0552/eos-5.html#eos-13)

> **Solaris Static System Libraries**
>
> This announcement applies only to 32-bit static-system libraries and
> statically linked utilities. Sixty-four-bit static system libraries
> and utilities have never been provided.
>
> Support for 32-bit Solaris static-system libraries and statically
> linked utilities is no longer provided in Solaris. Of particular note,
> support for the static C library (/usr/lib/libc.a) is no longer
> provided in Solaris.
>
> Applications that are linked with existing static system libraries
> might not work correctly in Solaris. Only applications that are
> dynamically linked with the system libraries that provide the Solaris
> application binary interface (ABI) are designed for future
> compatibility.
>
> Applications that directly depend on the behavior of system traps might not work correctly in Solaris. Applications that link with non-Sun libraries that directly depend on the behavior of system traps, typically libraries that provide substitute ABI functions, might not work correctly in Solaris.